# primefaces selectCheckboxMenu Grouping

Tags: java, primefaces

i have primefaces selectCheckboxMenu

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu  id="menu" style="width:100%" label="select Copies">
<f:selectItems value="#{newCorBean.copies}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

and i want to apply grouping option like selectOneMenu

```
    List<SelectItem> contactList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    SelectItemGroup g1  = dataAccessService.convertUserListToItemGroup(dataAccessService.findAllManagers(usr));
    g1.setLabel("mangers copies");
    contactList.add(g1);
    SelectItemGroup g2  = dataAccessService.convertUserListToItemGroup(dataAccessService.findUsersInDept(usr));
    g2.setLabel(" employees copies");
    contactList.add(g2);
```

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible jet, but there is an issue for this functionality see [primefaces-issues #500](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/500), maybe they will release it soon (*it is marked for 5.3, although the issue is not closed yet*).